# error: could not find or load main class org.dspace.app.launcher.scriptlauncher

Tags: java, postgresql, dspace

I am trying to install dspace in my window 10. And when I tried to run dspace database migrate after mvn package command, I got this error error: could not find or load main class org.dspace.app.launcher.scriptlauncher caused by: java.lang.classnotfoundexception: org.dspace.app.launcher.scriptlauncher.

I checked all enviorment variables and my ant apache and solr is running good. Can it be a error from my postgresql database??
Can anyone help with this.

Comment: Update: It was my fault. I was trying to run this command in the same repository bin file while I need to run this command in the new ant fresh installed repo bin file.